# Site endlessly loading JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

Using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) I've noticed that my site Firefox 24 ESR is endlessly loading *scripts/index.js*. Chrome/IE freeze up. Disabling JavaScript stops the problem. In Firefox Fiddler won't show the requests until a *click*.

Testing *locally* I have disabled all `window.on` function (onload, onclick, onpop etc).

I'm not sure what else to test, here is the link...

---

In case anyone else comes across a similar issue check to make sure your *server* scripting isn't causing an error or effecting script files (e.g. mixing PHP in to JavaScript). I had a PHP error in my *onload.js* file though I have no idea why this would make Firefox request *index.js* several hundred times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is reporting an error when the browser requests the script:

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (onload.js, line 0)